# Add different sections and their inside items in TableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am working on a Todo app, 
I have an array that contains projects and the todos inside them. 
for example in the first project, the title of todos is something like that:

```
cell.title.text = project[0].todo[indexPath.row].title
```

I really need help that how can I create these kind of structure in the `cellForRowAt`, I want to say for example in the section 0, it shows the todos inside the `project[0]` and go on with other project. 
could you help me on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have the following structures for the data:

```
struct Todo {
  let title: String
}

struct Project {
  let name: String
  let todo: [Todo]
}
```

Then you must implement the TableView's data source functions:

```
// Number of sections corresponds to number of projects
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
  return project.count
}

// Each section title corresponds to the project name
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
  return project[section].name
}

// Number of rows per section corresponds to the number to ToDos per project
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return project[section].todo.count
 }
```

Then your cellForRowAt function will dequeue cells from the table. You must use the `indexPath` variable to fetch the data; `indexPath.section` is the project's index, and `indexPath.row` property the todo inside a project.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "id", for: indexPath)
  cell.textLabel?.text = project[indexPath.section].todo[indexPath.row].title
  return cell
}
```

I created a little project to test this and used the following function to generate random data:

```
@objc private func generateData(_ sender: Any) {
  project.removeAll()
  let minimumProjects = 7
  let minimumTodos = 3
  for _ in 0...(minimumProjects + Int.random(in: 0...7)) {
    let projectName = "\(Int.random(in: 374...93842))"
    let newTodos = (minimumTodos...(minimumTodos + Int.random(in: 0...5))).map {_ in
      Todo(title: "Title: \(Int.random(in: 0...123))")
    }

    let newProject = Project(name: "Project \(projectName)", todo: newTodos)
    project.append(newProject)
  }
  DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
    self?.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    self?.table.reloadData()
  }
}
```

The app looks like this:
[image]